# Multithreading in wxWidgets GUI apps?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I'm having problem (basically, I'm confused.) while trying to create a worker thread for my wxWidgets GUI application that WILL MODIFY one of the GUI property itself. (In this case, wxTextCtrl::AppendText).

So far, I have 2 source files and 2 header files for the wx program itself (excluding my own libs, MySQL lib, etc), say MainDlg.cpp which contains a derived class of wxFrame called 'MainDlg' and MainForm.cpp which contains a derived class of wxApp called 'MainForm'.

MainForm.cpp

```
#include "MainHeader.h" // contains multiple header files

IMPLEMENT_APP(MainForm)

bool MainForm::OnInit()
{
    MainDlg *Server = new MainDlg(wxT("App Server 1.0"), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE - wxRESIZE_BORDER - wxMAXIMIZE_BOX);
    Editor->Show();

    return true;
}
```

MainDlg.cpp:

```
#include "MainHeader.h"

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MainDlg, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(6, MainDlg::StartServer)
EVT_BUTTON(7, MainDlg::StopServer)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

CNETServerConnection *cnServCon;
std::string ServerIP, DBHost, DBUser, DBName, DBPass;
int UserCapacity, DBPort, ServerPort;
MYSQL *sqlhnd;

MainDlg::MainDlg(const wxString &title, long style) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(301, 230), style)
{
    cnServCon = new CNETServerConnection(100);
    this->InitializeComponent();
}

void MainDlg::InitializeComponent()
{
    this->SetTitle(wxT("App Server 1.0"));
    this->SetSize(396, 260);
    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxSystemSettings::GetColour(wxSYS_COLOUR_3DFACE));
    this->Centre();

    statBox = new wxTextCtrl(this, 4, wxT("Welcome to AppServer 1.0\n\n"), wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(371, 141), wxTE_MULTILINE | wxTE_READONLY);

    //.................................
}

void MainDlg::StartServer(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    this->startBtn->Enable(false);
    this->AppendStatus(wxT("\nLoading server configuration... "));

    //.................................

    this->AppendStatus(wxT("OK\n\nServer ready!\n\n"));

    // When the server is ready, I need to run a thread
    // that will update the statBox (through AppendStatus func or wxTextCtrl::AppendText directly)
    // regularly without interrupting the GUI itself.
    // Because the thread will contain a while-loop
    // to make the program keep receiving message from clients.

    this->startBtn->Hide();
    this->stopBtn->Show();
    this->cmdBtn->Enable();
    this->cmdBox->Enable();
}

void MainDlg::StopServer(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    //...................................
}

void MainDlg::AppendStatus(const wxString &message)
{
    statBox->AppendText(message);
}

// Well, here is the function I'd like to run in a new thread
void MainDlg::ListenForMessages()
{
    int MsgSender = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(!cnServCon->GetNewMessage())
            continue;

        if(MsgSender = cnServCon->GetJoiningUser())
            this->AppendStatus(wxT("Someone connected to the server."));
    }
}
```

I also found an usage example of wxThread from [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c):

```
class MessageThread : public wxThread
{
private:
    MessageThread(const MessageThread &copy);
public:
    MessageThread() : wxThread(wxTHREAD_JOINABLE)
    {
    }

    void *Entry(void)
    {
        // My works goes here
        return;
    }
};

wxThread *CreateThread()
{
        wxThread *_hThread = new MessageThread();

        _hThread->Create();
        _hThread->Run();

        return _hThread;
}
```

But I don't know how to associate it with my program and make it able to modify my GUI property (statBox).

Any kind of help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that `Entry` returns `ExitCode`, not `void*`. So be sure you override the correct method (use `ExitCode`) instead.

Comment: I also want to warn you about `wxThread`'s wait function. On windows, its wait will block, *but still processes arbitrary events*. So it can happen that in an event handler you call wait on a joinable thread, and it processes events during waiting, and then it calls yet another event handler (called "yielding" in wx terms), which IMHO is totally stupid. That's the main reason i've always used another thread class that fixed it, never `wxThread`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest is to create an event type id, and use a `wxCommandEvent` using the type id, set its string member ("evt.SetText"), and send the event to one of your windows (using `AddPendingEvent`). In the handler of that event, you can then call `AppendText` on your control using the text you sent (`evt.GetText`), because you are in the GUI thread by then.

```
// in header
DECLARE_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_MY_EVENT, -1)

// in cpp file
DEFINE_EVENT_TYPE(wxEVT_MY_EVENT)

// the event macro used in the event table. id is the window id you set when creating 
// the `wxCommandEvent`. Either use -1 or the id of some control, for example. 
EVT_COMMAND(window-id, event-id, handler-function)
```

Here is an overview how it works: [Custom Events](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_eventhandlingoverview.html#customevents).