# Windows threads - how to make a method a thread function in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, pointers

I can't pass a pointer to method to the CreateThread function, of course.
What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple example of threading in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)

Comment: Use CreateThread with caution, as it doesn't initialize the C (and possibly the C++) runtime for the new thread.

Comment: Really? How to initialize the runtime manually?

Answer (score 7):

If using a class, some pattern like this usually works well:

.h

```
static UINT __cdecl StaticThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam);
UINT ThreadFunc();
```

.cpp

```
// Somewhere you launch the thread
AfxBeginThread(
    StaticThreadFunc,
    this);  

UINT __cdecl CYourClass::StaticThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CYourClass *pYourClass = reinterpret_cast<CYourClass*>(pParam);
    UINT retCode = pYourClass->ThreadFunc();

    return retCode;
}

UINT CYourClass::ThreadFunc()
{ 
    // Do your thing, this thread now has access to all the classes member variables
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I often do this:

```
class X {
private:
    static unsigned __stdcall ThreadEntry(void* pUserData) {
        return ((X*)pUserData)->ThreadMain();
    }

    unsigned ThreadMain() {
         ...
    }
};
```

And then I pass `this` as user data to the thread creator function (_beginthread[ex], CreateThread, etc)

Answer (score 4):

The most common way is to create a Thread class that has a run() method and a start() method (these names borrowed from the Java Thread class). run() is a pure virtual that you overload in a class derived from Thread to do the actual work. The method start() internally calls CreateThread passing the this pointer via reinterpret_cast to void*. The Thread class has also a threadEntryPoint() static function that you pass to CreateThread. In threadEntryPoint() you do a reinterpret_cast back to Thread* and then call run() on it.

If there's one situation in which you just want a method of another class to be executed on a separated thread (without having to inherit from the Thread class) you can create a Thread-derived class that receives a pair object+method pointers in the constructor, and calls them in run(). To ease things up, make this derived class a template. Also take a look on boost for functor adaptors.

Comment: thanks. as i understood, i only nedd to add one static function to my class and one method to start, threadEntryPoint functionality will be realized in the statiс method.

Comment: Yes, if you want to do this once-only it's as simple as that. If you want to reuse it in other places, it'd be better to isolate the code in a separated class.

Answer (score 1):

CreateThread won't take a pointer to a member function. You can wrap the member function in a static function which takes the object pointer through lpParameter.

Answer (score 1):

CreateThread's lpStartAddress is of type DWORD (WINAPI *PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(LPVOID lpThreadParameter) and this is incompatible with the member function since the member function has an implicit **this** pointer in its signature. So create a static function and pass the class pointer as the argument to the thread function.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about **Native** `CreateThread` Method you would probably need to do following

```
CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&MyThreadProc,NULL,NULL,&threadId);
```

Where your callback method is defined as

```
void MyThreadProc()
{
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do this - the cast here is a problem: generally speaking, you should never cast a function just to make things work. Instead you should pass MyThreadProc without a cast, and then change void MyThreadProc() to be DWORD WINAPI MyThreadProc(LPVOID), which is what CreateThread is expecting. Passing a function with a different number or type of params or calling convention than an API is expecting can lead to a messed-up stack.