# If ampersands aren't needed for function pointers, why does boost::bind require one?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-bind

I've always believed that function pointers don't require an ampersand:

[Do function pointers need an ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917043/do-function-pointers-need-an-ampersand)

Yet, every example I've seen of using `boost::bind` shows one, and my compiler - in most situations - gives a typically inscrutable error message if it's omitted.

```
synchronize(boost::bind(&Device::asyncUpdate , this, "ErrorMessage"));  // Works

synchronize(boost::bind(Device::asyncUpdate , this, "ErrorMessage"));   // Fails
```

Am I wrong in assuming that `boost::bind`'s first parameter is basically function pointer?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, friendship shouldn't make any difference, the & is required for forming a pointer to member.

Comment: Note that `static` members functions behave like free functions w.r.t function pointers. They can't bind to member pointers and you can omit `&`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Function pointers don't need it, **member** function pointers do.

`Device::asyncUpdate` is member function, as you could guess because it is being bound to `this`.

Here's a normative quote from n3337, 5.3.1/4

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualiﬁed-id not enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @Roddy Friendship shouldn't make any difference. Can you show a compilable example of what you mean? That example isn't very useful :)

Comment: Yes, it was bad, wasn't it ;-) Confirmed as a compiler bug in BCB2010

Comment: @jrok, Could you give me a rationale of making such a needless-seeming rule?

Comment: @xmllmx: The omission of `&` is only allowed for compatibility with C. Since C did not have member functions, C++ can be strict when it comes to pointers to member functions.