# Calling true virtual function in base class

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, virtual

Edit: The correct title should have been "Calling overloaded true virtual function in base class", as that was a big part of the problem.

I have a base class with a true virtual function and a couple of other, normal ones. One of the normal ones calls the virtual function in a thread, and I get an error in that line, which I don't understand. I guess it has something to do with the thread, but as the base class is abstract, and every derived class has to actually implement the virtual function, there should be no problem. Maybe it's something completely different. This is more or less what it looks like:

```
class Base {
    virtual int getInfo(int a) = 0; // the culprit?

    void getInfo();         // is implemented, calls getInfo(int); Does  
                            // actually have the same name. Works perfectly fine.

    void getThreadedInfo(); // for details, see below

}

// ..later..

Base::getThreadedInfo() {
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<maxThreads; i++) {
        threads.push_back(thread(getInfo, i)); // this is line 85
    }
    ...
}
```

The complete error message is:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'Base::getInfo': function call missing argument list; use '&Base::getInfo' to create a pointer to member   
c:\path\to\base.cpp 85  1   Project

Error   2   error C2661: 'std::thread::thread' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments   
c:\path\to\base.cpp 85  1   Project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(static_cast<int (Base::*)(int)>(&Base::getInfo), this, i));
```

as `&Base::getInfo` is ambiguous.

Comment: I thought the overload might be the problem, thank you for showing how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple different things going on.

The first, simplest one to fix is what the first error message is telling you about--you need to use the `&` operator with `getInfo` in `thread`'s argument list to create a function pointer.

The second issue is that the call to `getInfo` in `thread`'s contructor needs an additional argument. In addition to the explicit `int a`, since `getInfo` is not static, it takes an implicit `Base* this`. So `this` needs to be added.

The third, trickiest problem is that `Base` has two overloads of `getInfo`, so you need to make it explicit which one you want.

Putting all three things together, you need to have... exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24125472/3549027) said while I was typing. :)

Comment: I don't get why I have to add the & and the 'this'-argument. In the thread-documentation on cplusplus.com the initialize threads with   std::thread second (bar,0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0). Is it because I am calling a member function? If yes .. why does it work that way?

Comment: Think about it this way: If you didn't pass `this`, how would the compiler know which `Base` object you wanted to call `getInfo` on? When you call the function the normal way with something like `o.getInfo(3)`, it's obvious that the object to the left of the operator should be used as `this`. But when you're using the function generically, you have to provide a value for `this` explicitly.

Comment: My previous comment only addressed half your question. In response to the other half (`&`), yes, the difference is that you're dealing with a member function here.

Comment: I guess I assumed that "this" was implicit, as the member function was the only function of that name visible in the scope of the call. But it does make sense, thank you.

Comment: Ok; I can see why someone would assume that. You're right, *in theory*, if you're binding to a member function of class `C` from within another member function of `C`, the `this` value for the function call could be populated implicitly with the current `this`. But then some sort of actual change to the language would be required in order to implement `thread`, `bind`, and anything else that uses member function pointers. In any case, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I still haven't answered you whole question. I'm actually not sure why you're allowed to omit the `&` with free functions but not member functions (you still *can* use it with free functions if you want to).

Comment: A comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312186/if-ampersands-arent-needed-for-function-pointers-why-does-boostbind-require) claims the `&` is only optional with free functions in order to allow compatibility with C.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for digging so deep into it, I appreciate it!