# Pass a function-pointer name to C Preprocessor

Tags: c, function-pointers, c-preprocessor

I have a registry for functions in my **C** code, and I have to provide an API to register custom functions at compile time to the registry.

Example: 
The "customer" side of code should like:

```
int a_test_function_a(){
    return 13;
}
int init(void){
    add_command(a_test_function_a);
}
```

In my registry code I defined this macro:

```
#define add_command(NAME)   do{                 \
    command_registry = avl_tree_add(            \
    command_registry                            \
    , #NAME                                     \
    , &##NAME                                   \
    , &command_handler);                        \
    } while(0)
```

Here is what I do not understand. The output of gcc -E replace the string like expected:

```
do{ command_registry = avl_tree_add( command_registry , "a_test_function_a" , &a_test_function_a , &command_handler); } while(0);
```

But the compiler throw a error:

```
src/commands/commandRegisterTest.c:18:5: error: pasting formed '&a_test_function_a', an invalid
  preprocessing token
add_command(a_test_function_a);
^
src/commands/../../../src/commands/command_api.h:18:8: note: expanded from macro 'add_command'
, &##NAME                                   \
   ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I do this, that I do not have to call `add_command('name', &function);` by my own. I will register the function by it's name and just call the `add_command(name)` thing. 
Besides a solution, why is the preprocessor replace the line but fails? This doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: you don't need ##, & of pasting does not make sense, but & of function, does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions and function pointers are usually equivalent, i.e. you can [simply omit the `& ##`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917043/do-function-pointers-need-an-ampersand) and it'll work anyway but the preprocessor will be happy.

Anyway, you can simply remove the `##` operator and it'll probably work, too. `& var` is fine so concatenation is not necessary.

Comment: hm, not in my case:  expanded from macro 'add_command'
    , ##NAME

Comment: Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) by the way

Comment: Does GCC compile your code (with the ampersand)? If yes it might be a bug in clang.

Comment: with or without, gcc fails on ##NAME.

Comment: You don't need the ## - leave it out.