# Suppress system() console output

Tags: c++, unix, console

I'm using `system()` to open and close an external program with which my code communicates. However, every time I use the `system()` function, I get the console output I would get if I was calling the program from a normal terminal/shell, e.g. every time I call `system(killall [program] &)` I get a *Terminated* message. Is there a way to suppress this type of outputs?

Comment: Redirect their output to `/dev/null`, as always.

Comment: @Jon I'm already trying that, but I still get "Terminated" messages on the console.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [execlp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) instead of system ;)

https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ENV04-C.+Do+not+call+system()+if+you+do+not+need+a+command+processor

Comment: Problem is, with `execlp` I have I get stuck waiting for the command to finish; What I was looking for was something that would allow me to just start a second process, that runs in parallel with the main program, like I get with `system("[program] &")`

Comment: @joaocandre you should use [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c), put your `execlp` in `task1`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Apparently, using `task1.join()` implies waiting for `task1` to finish, so it's not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: @joaocandre just don't call `join()`, the task1 should be executed at the same time without blocking your main thread.

Comment: not using `join()` results in `task1` not being lauched at all. I've also tried using `detach` same result.