# Lauch a program in the background

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, execution

I've been trying to launch and close an external program at certain point during my code, and was relying on `system()` calls to accomplish that. However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17580531/2340002) it was suggested that I use `execlp` and a separate `std::thread` entirely, in order to suppress console outputs.

The problem is, both of these solutions imply waiting for the program to close, which I want to avoid, as I need to communicate with that program (right now through UNIX sockets). Is there any way to use either `execlp` or  `std::thread` to lauch a program in background, as I do with `system([program]&)`?

Comment: When you use the `exec` family of functions, you can't use threads. You have to create a completely new process using the `fork` system call.

Comment: As for how to do it, there are many, **many**, examples all over the Internet. A simple search in your favorite search engine will find you hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 1):

actually you **can** use threads :) but with care...
the simplest way to do `fork` **before** spawning any thread in parent/all process/es. then, after `fork` you may start any needed threads (anywhere you want: in parent as well as in child process).

doing `fork` there is no threads started automatically in a child process, but I suppose you don't need them... child usually do some preparations and `exec` required process, so you don't need to respawn any threads in it. (anyway if you want, you can do it!). then, you have to watch your child via `waitpid` and wait for it's death.

PS: also read `man pthread_atfork` if you really need some threads in a child.