# Optimizing console programs

Tags: c++, console

I have a console application that is doing intense calculations, and it takes several hours to complete. I can run as many as I want at a given moment, and they all run at exactly the same speed. That means my computer has the ability to go faster, so why isn't it? I want my computer to take 100% of its processing power and dedicate it to this one program.

I can easily cut time in half by putting half of the work in one program and half of the work in another, and have them communicate through a txt file or something. Is there any way I can make it go faster without doing that? Task Manager's priority doesn't change anything.

Comment: [Parallelization](https://www.google.com/search?q=Parallelization)

Comment: one approach can be creating several exe files each doing a part of calcuations and running them simulatneously.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus "I can easily cut time in half by putting half of the work in one program and half of the work in another, and have them communicate through a txt file or something." I know that, but that is annoying for the user.

Comment: do you want to have only one exe file?! you can have a moderating exe file which runs other exe files or dlls and shows the results they collect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... There's always multithreading:
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c), for example.

But it's always a complicated process, especially for C++. I'm afraid you'll have to google some tutorials for your particular case.

Here are some: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm), [codebase](http://codebase.eu/tutorial/posix-threads-c/), plenty more around. There are a lot of methods, achieved by many distinct [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C++_multi-threading_libraries), and none of them could be considered simple.

Comment: #include <thread> was really easy, already implemented and now its running an order of magnitude faster :) (Says I have to wait 6 minutes to accept your answer)

Comment: @Nicholas Pipitone In that case, I was either rubbish at it or it wasn't implemented as well at the time. Do be careful tho - there are many pitfalls which might result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: Lol, maybe in my case it was just really easy to implement. My program is deeply nested in 26 for loops, so I just took the nested part and split it into four functions, threaded each one, and put a *.join() at the end and it sped through the whole thing.