# Loading Data Sources with Threads Example

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder

I currently have an application written in Rad Studio C++ for windows. It uses ADO connections to load data from SQL Server. Since it's a large amount of data it takes a long time to load all the data.

I would like to activate the Data Sources in the background. Can anyone help me with an example to do the following code in a separate thread.

```
DataModule->ADO_DataSource->Active = true;
```

Thanks

Comment: I got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c?rq=1