# In Visual C++ , Call A Function And Execute Rest Of The Program, Simultaneously

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Parallel programming or threading, it should be for Visual C++.

A function takes a large amount of time To complete, as a result the rest of the code will not be executed for ex

```
main()
{  
    timeconsumingcode();
    nextstep();
}
```

`nextstep()` Will not Take Place Until timeconsumingcode() gets over;

hence i want `timeconsumingcode()` and `nextstep()` to run simultaneously

I would like to know how we do it for Visual C++

Comment: While the linked question is quite similar, it predates C++11.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c might be relevant

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you should be able to use [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) or, as @MSalters proposed in the comment, [`std::thread(&timeconsumingcode).detach();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). On C++03 you should be able to model the same with the [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Comment: Or just `std::thread(&timeconsumingcode).detach();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use C Runtime Function `_beginthreadex`. You should change the signature of your `timeconsumingcode` a bit.

```
unsigned int __stdcall timeconsumingcode(void* pdata);
main()
{  
  _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, timeconsumingcode, NULL, 0, NULL);
  nextstep()
}
```

Please have look at MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx for more info