# How can I do Multitasking in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, multitasking

For instance take example of a program which calculates the time you take to type a paragraph and displays the time you took ( at the end ). Here our program is simultaneously performing two tasks :
 1.Waiting for user to type ( taking input ).
          2.A clock behind counts the time elapsed .

How can I accomplish both the tasks during execution ( at the same time ) . 
  [ OK ! You may think of subtracting final & initial time which we may get by system but I want multitask to take place .]

I tried a lot searching for standard library functions but none of them do it .
I think the only way to make multitask happen is smart algorithm  of the program which does many tasks simultaneously as well as efficiently . Am I wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c

Comment: Do you want a C answer or a C++ answer? The correct idiomatic answers are VERY different.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do multitasking: First, decide if you're coding in `C` or `C++`. Second, choose `C++`. Third, read up on `std::thread`.

Comment: @stefan: Fourth, read an entire book (or maybe several) on concurrent programming to learn about all the issues of synchronization, communication, different threading techniques, etc.

Comment: @FredLarson Oh yeah, I usually forget to do this step :D

Comment: @FredLarson: Fifth - start pulling your hair out if, even after all your best efforts, you still run into concurrency-related issues, as you inevitably will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which is of course part of the standard.

This will not work if using C however or older c++ compilers.

An alternative is [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html)

Comment: In C11, there is `thrd_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Probably multithreading. Use [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

[Although, in your example it's not needed. Just

```
int time = getTime();
// run program
int endTime = getTime();
printf("%d\n", endTime - time);
```

]

Comment: @const_ref; Because there is no `std::thread` in C

Comment: @haccks but there is in c++ which is also tagged

Comment: @const_ref; I can see that's why I commented.

Comment: @const_ref When someone tags both C and C++, I think it is fair game to give an answer that works only in one or the other.

Comment: @crashmstr So why not comment giving the one that works OS independently and is part of the standard. In OP post "searching for standard library functions but none of them do it"..which is of course not true

Comment: If C, then why not `thrd_t`? (Ok maybe because there's barely any C11 compilers, but still :) )