# Simple error with the creation of a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I try to remember of how threads work, I see that with `C++11` it simplify the creation and utilisation of it. I use the answer to this post [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c) for just create a simple thread.

But there's difference between me and the answer of the post, I'm not in a main, so I create my thread in a constructor, and it's not the same parameters.

Here's my simple code and what I try to do:

I'm in a class `mainWindow.cpp` :

```
//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(lancerServeur, NULL);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
void MainWindow::lancerServeur(){
    std::cout << "Le serveur se lance";
}
```

The errors are :

```
expected ';' before 't1'

statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function thread t1(lancerServeur, NULL);
```

I think my parameters for `thread t1(lancerServeur, NULL);` are false.

Could you explain me how it works ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `std::cout`, so I'm assuming that the is no `using namespace std;` or the like somewhere before the `thread`. Try `std::thread`.

Try a lambda `std::thread t1([this](){this->lancerServeur();});`

Don't forget to `th1.join()` before exiting the constructor, else `std::terminate` will be called in the `thread` destructor.

If the thread in `th1` will run for a while, then make it a class member variable and then the initialisation will look like `th1 = std::move(std::thread t1([this](){this->lancerServeur();}));` In the class destructor, `th1.join();`

Comment: I've got this when I use std in front of thread : no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, NULL)'

Comment: The function 'MainWindow::lancerServeur` should be static or use a lambda `std::thread([this](){this->lancerServeur();});`

Comment: If I put it static I've got this :no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(int))()>'
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;

Comment: Remove the NULL, the `lancerServeur()` function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: It compile ! But now : Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function. Happen when I try to lauch it. I wasn't thinking this was so hard to create a thread ^^'

Comment: You've created the thread on the stack in your constructor. It probably is done by the time the constructor is complete. You need to wait for it to complete `th1.join()` else `std::terminate` will be called in the `std::thread` destructor.

Comment: It works, you could edit your answer, and I will accept it, but I've got a problem, this thread is supposed to be a server, so it won't stop, because i'm gonna put a while(1) in it, so if I use t1.join , it won't laucnh the application and stay in lancerServeur no ?