# Running a periodic loop in background in C++/C

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to create C++ program in the sense of embedded hardware programs that work in real time. The main loop in my C++ program uses a delay time of 250milliseconds. It's like:

```
int main()
{
  do{
   doSomething();
   delay(250);
  }while(1)
}
```

The delay in main loop is crucial for my program to operate. 
I need to check something else using 5ms delays.

```
sideJob()
{
   while(1){
    checkSomething();
    delay(5);
   }
}
```

How do I define the function sideJob to run at the same with the main loop. All in all, I need to get the hang of threading by using, if possible, simple functions. I'm using Linux. Any help will be greately appreaciated.

**EDIT:** This is what I got so far, But I want to run the sideJob and main thread at the same time.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

//The function we want to make the thread run.
void task1(string msg)
{

     cout << "sideJob Running " << msg;

}

int main()
{  
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");

    //Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
    while(1){
        printf("Continuous Job\n");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you, instead of `delay(250)`, call `checkSomething()` 50 times in a loop with `delay(5)` in between?

Comment: thats my last resort, cause the timing is really important and the 5ms thing and 250ms thing should not stop at any time

Comment: There's plenty of pthreads tutorials out there on the internets.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: a simple solution, not ruled out by the information you provide, is to make two programs and run them at the same time.

Comment: Note that if `checkSomething()` takes 1 ms to run, then you will run for 1 ms and sleep for 5 ms, for a total delay of 6 ms between periodic checks.  If you use one background loop for both tasks, you will cause both tasks to drift if you don't pay attention to this detail.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I want to do exactly what you say, but I want to pass arguments between those two executables. That information would help me plenty as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use different threads in order to do this tasks in parallel.

To learn for more about this, look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Threading).
For an example on StackOverflow, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c).

You can also find plenty of tutorials out there (for example, [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm)).

Comment: @mozcelikors Ok, take your time.
To all StackOverflow members: If downvoted, I would appreciate if any comment follows here for me in order to update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @mozcelikors About update: This is the meaning of threads, to run parallely, on the same time.