# Why can't I declare a thread in an if in C++? Is there a way around?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to use threading in an if statement.

The following code gives an error saying t1 in t1.join is not declared in this scope. Is there a way to make the loop skip the first thread operation and start multithreading for the other passes?

```
  #include <thread>
  void someFunction() {/*someTask*/}

 void main() {
     bool isFirstRun = true;
     while(true){

     if(isFirstRun==false){std::thread t1(someFunction);}

     //some long task

     if(isFirstRun==false){t1.join}
     if(isFirstRun){isFirstRun = false;}
     }
 }
```

More generally, is there a way to create a thread like a global variable in C++ and control its execution anywhere in the code? I saw the following in java and thought this might solve my problem if implemented in C++:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1")); 
//some tasks here
t1.start(); 
//some tasks here
t1.join();
```

Comment: The thread destructor is called when the if block ends... since the variable is in that scope only

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: Declare it in another scope...

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads. This is no different from `if (some condition) { int x = 5; } if (x) /* error, x not defined */ {...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if(isFirstRun==false){std::thread t1(someFunction);}
> ```

The scope of `t1` is limited to the block following the first `if` statement—the curly braces in the statement quoted above. It subsequently goes out of scope and is therefore not accessible later in the function.

If you want it to remain in scope, define it *outside* of an `if` block, perhaps at the scope of your `main()` function.

> I saw the following in java and thought this might solve my problem if implemented in C++:
>
> ```
> Thread t1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1"));
> ```

Certainly you can `new` up an object (`new` returns a pointer), but C++ isn't Java. You should not follow the same programming patterns. If creating the object on the stack is sufficient, then do that.

> ```
> void main()
> ```

Also, there is no such function as `void main()` in C++; the entry point returns `int`.

---

A simple example of implementing threading in C++ is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229853/366904).

Comment: do you mean I should do `if(firstRun){/*without threading*/}else{/*same code with threading*/}`

Comment: You know how you defined the `isFirstRun` variable at the beginning of the `main()` function? You can do the exact same thing with `t1`.

Comment: Yeah but it starts running immediately then. I want it to start running in while loop, after the first run.

Comment: Well, you can declare the variable at an outer scope (`std::thread t1;`) so that it will be default-constructed, which doesn't start a thread. Then, when you want to start the thread, you can create a new thread and assign it to `t1`: `t1 = std::thread(...);`

Comment: That was what I was looking for, thanks.