# how to run two loops in game C++

Tags: c++

i am about to make a game where a plane is moving on x axis and the cannon use to hit the plan with cannon ball and the plane has to crash i did all what i can but i got a serious problem 
problem 1: when plan is moving i can't use canon cause both are using for loop and they have to wait for each other to finish
problem 2: because of cleardevice(); function its so difficult for me to continue both movement of the cannon ball and plan anybody having any idea what i am missing would be appreciated its very important thanks in advance

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <windows.h>
void fire();
void canon();
void plan();
void plan_move();


int main( )
{
initwindow(800, 500, "First Sample");

canon();
 plan_move();
 plan();



getch();
return 0;
}
void fire()
{
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<370;i++)
 {
         circle(363, 400-i, 13);
         setcolor(WHITE);
         delay(5);
         canon(); 
         cleardevice();


         }
  }

void canon()
{
 line(350,450,350,400);
 line(380,450,380,400);
 circle(365,400,15);
 circle(365,470,25);
  }
void plan()
{
line(25,70,50,70);
line(25,30,50,30);
line(80,70,50,30);
line(80,70,50,70);
line(25,30,25,70);

} 

void plan_move()
{
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<700;i++)
   {
     line(25+i,70,50+i,70);
     line(25+i,30,50+i,30);
     line(80+i,70,50+i,30);
     line(80+i,70,50+i,70);
     line(25+i,30,25+i,70);

     delay(8);
     canon();
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
         {
         fire();
         } 
           cleardevice();


          }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to try running the loop on a new thread. See this post for an example: [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)

Comment: Overkill and unnecessary.

Comment: i am using Dev C++ unfortunately its not that simple in that

Comment: @HazratBilal _"i am using Dev C++"_ Huh?? It's just simple as that. What's your toolchain and compiler flag settings?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious then what would the ideal solution be?

Comment: One big for loop that does both.

Comment: Just create a single top level controlling loop and call an update function for each frame with the amount of time elapsed since the last update.

Comment: please share some example i can't understand i am newbie take the block of my codes and share some possible solution would be appreciated