# C++ How can I run three diffrent parallel_for functions at once apart from using tbb::task_group?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb, parallel.for

I have code where I have to run parallel_for (independent from each other) at once parallely.

Code is something like:

```
tbb::parallel_for(range1,func1());//first

tbb::parallel_for(range2,func2());//second

tbb::parallel_for(range3,func3());//third
```

I have tried using task_group. Is there any other method available?

Comment: What *have* you tried? How did your attempt work or fail? Can you perhaps show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why?  If the three are large enough, each will saturate your cpus and only modest "rundown"/"runup" wasted cpu will occur if you do it in series, assuming you need all 3 finished to proceed.

Comment: and why do you want another approach if task_group works well?

Comment: @Anton The "runup" I am getting with task group is marginal. Also I wanted  to know which other methods will be suitable for appication like this.

Comment: It's rather not because the choice of task_group. As Yakk mentioned above, check your problem size first or because nobody's remember to warm up threads before starting to measure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to run any parallel algorithm in parallel, you want just run it inside another parallel algorithm of your choice. `task_group` is just one example. The simplest approach for your case is to use [`parallel_invoke`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_invoke_func.html):

```
tbb::parallel_invoke([]{
        tbb::parallel_for(range1,func1);//first
    }, []{
        tbb::parallel_for(range2,func2);//second
    }, []{
        tbb::parallel_for(range3,func3);//third
    }
);
```

but one can choose to use another `parallel_for` over array of ranges and function pointers, or use `parallel_pipeline`, `parallel_for_each`, or raw low-level `tbb::task`.

Comment: You should remember that the scheduling algorithm for tasks in TBB may give you unexpected results.  If you want all the tasks will progress at the same rate, you may be disappointed, because TBB uses a greedy (unfair) scheduling algorithm.

Your tasks will all complete, and with TBB you won't oversubscribe the system, but they may still complete one-at-a-time.

Comment: You could also schedule multiple graph nodes each with a parallel algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them each in a single [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and make a [join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) afterwards. See also [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c).

Comment: that's bad approach since it is vulnerable to oversubscription because does not use tbb's worker threads

Comment: besides over-subscription, it introduces a lot of overhead for thread creation and joining.

Comment: This critic is true.