# Correct way to initialize threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a simple class lets call it worker

```
class Worker{
  Worker(){
    // Initialize
  }
  void runWorker(){
     while(1){ 
        //Do work
     }
  }
}
```

What is the correct C++ way to initialize and run thing class on a new thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple example of threading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266168/simple-example-of-threading-in-c)

Comment: @tambre Im more interested in the C++ way to design multithreaded objects.  That question has a function that is then run on a new thread.  In my case, I have a class that I want to run in a new thread

Comment: "I have a class that I want to run in a new thread" - One does not run classes. One runs *functions*.

Comment: okay... I have a member function that I want to run.  This member function will be modifying private members of my class.  Is there a standard way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++11 or later, threads are built in.

```
std::thread t([]() {
    Worker w; // construct as normal
    w.runWorker();
};
```

If you want to use the same `Worker` in multiple threads, you can construct it outside your thread and capture it in the lambda.

```
Worker w;
std::thread t1([&w]() {
    w.runWorker();
});
std::thread t2([&w]() {
    w.runWorker();
});
```

If you use the latter method, make sure `w` doesn't go out of scope since it's capturing by reference.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using C++98?

Comment: Not using standard C++.

Comment: The standard didn't add `<thread>` until C++11, for code before that you'd have to use something like `boost::thread` or `pthread`

Comment: wow, seems like a basic thing to have can't believe it wasnt added until much later

Comment: @Iliketoproveit • there were non-standard (in the context of the C++ language standard), non-very-portable (often platform specific) implementations prior to C++11.

Comment: @Iliketoproveit C++ is a very big umbrella. Some of the systems beneath it didn't (and still don't) have threads. Requiring compiler developers to implement threading support on these systems would likely have added C++ to the junk heap of compilers only used by academics.

Comment: If you call `runWorker` on an object shared between threads, it should be declared `const`